# Split string into dictionary

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, split

I have string like this "0 0.014E5" and I need it split into a Dictionary (in c#). Where the firs zero will be the key and the number in exp format will be the value.

Comment: awesome questions. key thing would be telling everybody what language do you want it in...

Comment: OK, added a C# code snippet to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python:

```
s = "0 0.014E5".split(' ')
d = {}
d[s[0]] = s[1] 
# alternatively you can use:
d[s[0]] = float(s[1])
```

In Java:

```
String[] s = "0 0.014E5".split(" ");
Map<String, double> d = new HashMap<String, double>();
d.put(s[0], Double.parseDouble(s[1]));
```

In C#:

```
string[] s = "0 0.014E5".Split(' ');
var d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
d.Add(s[0], s[1]);
```